# How to search for last two characters and then remove them?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would you go about searching for ND or RD in address like 200 162nd Street and removing it and having the output be : 200 162 Street

I know I need to do something like select RIGHT(address, 2);

The hard part is searching for the ND or RD and removing it after there is an unknown amount of characters before and after it, ie it can be Street, Boulevard, Avenue, etc

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
select RIGHT(address, 2);
```

Comment: What do you want to do actually? I guess you may want to change 2nd / 3rd into 2 / 3. Would `SELECT REPLACE(address, '2nd', '2')` works for you?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(
                                        REPLACE(address, '1st', '1'), 
                                        '2nd', '2'
                                    ), '3rd', '3'
                                ), '4th', '4'
                            ), '5th', '5'
                        ), '6th', '6'
                    ), '7th', '7'
                ), '8th', '8'
            ), '9th', '9'
        ), '0th', '0'
    ) AS "address"
FROM ..
```

Not a beauty to be honest.

Comment: Won't you need a replace for each digit 0-9?

Comment: @DaleK Obviously, yes. Not a pretty one.

Comment: I'd guess not 0, unless addresses exist like 0th Street. Nevermind... 10th...

Comment: "Obviously, yes" I wouldn't assume obviously, many question askers will assume your answer is 100% correct. For the sake of a short sentence saying as much it would be much clearer. And 0 does need to be handled, because this is only checking the last digit of what could be a longer number i.e. 100th street should become 100 street. Who knows why OP has such a requirement however

Comment: @DaleK You're right, I enhanced the answer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following is something you can try, using a combination of *patindex* and *stuff*.

```
with t as (
  select * from (values('200 162nd Street'),('23rd Street'),('The strand not this'))x(s)
)
select s as SourceString, IsNull(Stuff(s, NullIf(p,0) + 1, 2, ''), s) Removed
from t
cross apply (values(PatIndex('%[0-9][r,n][d][ ]%', s)))p(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Combination of approaches shown thus far. The `CASE` expression assumes one of these 2-letter strings only occurs once.

```sql
SELECT addr
    ,CASE WHEN pat != 0
            THEN STUFF(addr, pat + 1, 2, '')
        ELSE addr2
    END AS AddrProcessed
FROM (
    SELECT '200 160th Street' UNION ALL
    SELECT '200 161st Street' UNION ALL
    SELECT '200 162nd Street' UNION ALL
    SELECT '200 163rd Street' UNION ALL
    SELECT '200 164th Street' UNION ALL
    SELECT '200 165th Street' UNION ALL
    SELECT '200 166th Street' UNION ALL
    SELECT '200 167th Street' UNION ALL
    SELECT '200 168th Street' UNION ALL
    SELECT '200 169th Blvd'
    )t(addr)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(addr, '1st', '1'),'2nd','2'),'3rd','3')
    ,PATINDEX('%[0,4-9]th%', addr)
    )calc(addr2, pat)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use a substring or a find function in addition to your replace method. You didn't post what language you are attempting this in. In SQL you could just use the REPLACE function

For the string 'SQL Tutorial' if you want to replace all T's with M's then,
SELECT REPLACE('SQL Tutorial', 'T', 'M');

Results in the string becoming: SQL MuMorial

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp